# Can i create a url like google mail in cake php?

Tags: cakephp, routes

Hi The master CakePHP! I want to ask something.

I think the probem is so simple, Is it possible to generate a url in cakephp application like this? (This is google mail like url - http://mail.google.com/a/domain.com)

```
http://www.domain.com/a/[something]/[member]/[controller]/[action]
```

Where [something] is a dynamic variable, [member] is a prefix, [controller] and [action] is usual cakephp url element.

so I want to shift the usual CakePHP url to the right, or insert /a/something/ in the initial url.
In addition, [something] should be read from the controller action

thanks, your help would be very valuable to me and will really help me

**QUESTION v2:**
I have tried to add this routing into routes.php

```
Router::connect('/:code/:something/:controller/:action',
    array(),
    array('code'=>'a','pass'=>array('something'))
);
```

when i try to access a http://domain.local/a/pte/users/view, it's work, but it display an error when i try to access http://domain.local/a/pte/users

**QUESTION v3:**

So the simple question is:

> *How do I have a url like google (example above) without breaking the
>   default CakePHP routing?*

**QUESTION v4:** (Thank's for @Rui)

I tried to create this routing:

```
Router::connect('/:code/:something/:prefix/:controller/*',
    array(),
    array('code'=>'a','pass'=>array('something'))
);
```

It's ok when i try to access

`http://domain.local/a/pte/member/users` (The result is cake render member_index view, It's a great progress :-) ),

but there are several issue:

1. when i try to access `http://domain.local/a/pte/users` (*without prefix member*, i decided to display index function) it's failed (display an error AController did not defined)
2. When i create a link

   echo $html->link('test link',array('code'=>'a','something'=>'pte','member'=>true,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'another_view'));

it generate a link like this

```
http://domain.local/member/users/another_view/code:a/something:pte
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try in /app/config/routes.php:

```
<?php 
   Router::connect('/a/:something/:member/:controller/:action/*'); 
?>
```

And the action should be:

```
<?php 
    public function action($something = null, $member = null) { 
    /* action code */
    } 
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.. I have tried to write this routing  Router::connect('/:code/:something/:controller/:action',
  array(),
  array('code'=>'a','pass'=>array('something'))
 ); But that was just useful when i write http://www.domain.com/a/test/users/view and display an error when i write http://www.domain.com/a/test/users

Comment: For domain.com/a/test/users, add this route:

Router::connect('/a/:something/:member/:controller', array('action' => 'view'));

Let me know if it helps, it assumes view is your default action in a controller.

Comment: So far It is GREAT Rui! But when i try to access http://domain.local/a/pte/member/users, cake tell me that Error: The action view is not defined in controller UsersController, **Was not supposed to be member_view not just view because of i defined Prefix member in the core**

Comment: Yes cake is looking for action "View" in controller Users... that's why it's saying that error.....

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is routes prefixes... please check here http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing , let me know if it helps.